# Can't install anything cause "printer-driver- .... unmet dependencies"

Tags: linux-mint, apt, fontconfig

I'm trying to install GNU screen:

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

I receive following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 printer-driver-gutenprint : Depends: cups (>= 1.3.0)
 printer-driver-splix : Depends: cups (>= 1.5.0-3~)
E: Unmet dependencies. [u]Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages[/u] (or specify a solution).
```

Next I execute:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cups-bsd cups-client cups-common libcups2 libcups2:i386 libcupscgi1
  libcupsimage2 libcupsimage2:i386 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libgmp10
  libgmp10:i386 libgnutls-deb0-28 libgnutls-deb0-28:i386 libhogweed2
  libhogweed2:i386 libnettle4 libnettle4:i386 libp11-kit-dev libp11-kit0
  libp11-kit0:i386 libtasn1-6 libtasn1-6:i386 libtasn1-6-dev p11-kit-modules
Suggested packages:
  cups xpp gnutls-bin gnutls-bin:i386
Recommended packages:
  libtasn1-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  cups-core-drivers cups-daemon printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-splix
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgmp10:i386 libgnutls-deb0-28 libgnutls-deb0-28:i386 libhogweed2:i386
  libnettle4:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cups-bsd cups-client cups-common libcups2 libcups2:i386 libcupscgi1
  libcupsimage2 libcupsimage2:i386 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libgmp10
  libhogweed2 libnettle4 libp11-kit-dev libp11-kit0 libp11-kit0:i386
  libtasn1-6 libtasn1-6:i386 libtasn1-6-dev p11-kit-modules
20 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 4 to remove and 1809 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3284 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3698 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up fontconfig (2.11.1-0ubuntu6) ...
Regenerating fonts cache... failed.
See /var/log/fontconfig.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package fontconfig (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fontconfig
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And I can't install updates from Update manager - it throws alerts about " printer drivers packages have mistakes"

How to fix this?

`/var/log/fontconfig.log`:

```
[...]
/usr/local/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/.local/share/fonts: skipping, no such directory
Re-scanning /usr/share/fonts: fc-cache: symbol lookup error: fc-cache: undefined symbol: FcDirCacheRescan
```

`ldd /usr/bin/fc-cache` (sory I'm not sure, should I include the whole log):

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffcad59000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f5b50e3c000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5b50c1e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5b50858000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f5b505b5000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f5b5038b000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000056140f1b3000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f5b50171000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f5b4ff4b000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5b4fc45000)
```

head -n 50 /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list  :

```
==> /etc/apt/sources.list <==
#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 17 _Qiana_ - Release amd64 20140624]/ trusty contrib main non-free
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid main universe

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list <==
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid main universe

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cinelerra-ppa-ppa-trusty.list <==
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/cinelerra-ppa/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/cinelerra-ppa/ppa/ubuntu trusty main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/foobnix-team-foobnix-player-trusty.list <==
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/foobnix-team/foobnix-player/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/foobnix-team/foobnix-player/ubuntu trusty main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list <==
# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu trusty-getdeb apps 

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list <==
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list <==
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonoomph-openshot-edge-trusty.list <==
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonoomph/openshot-edge/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonoomph/openshot-edge/ubuntu trusty main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mc3man-trusty-media-trusty.list <==
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu trusty main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list <==
deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list <==
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com rosa main upstream import

deb http://extra.linuxmint.com rosa main

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty partner

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openshot_developers-ppa-trusty.list <==
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu trusty main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sunab-kdenlive-release-trusty.list <==
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/sunab/kdenlive-release/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/sunab/kdenlive-release/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: did you examine `/var/log/fontconfig.log` as the error message suggested?

Comment: @cas  i've updated fontconfig.log

Comment: the last line indicates a problem with `fc-cache`.  show output of `ldd /usr/bin/fc-cache`.  maybe try re-installing `fontconfig` package and all its dependencies.

Comment: @cas  whole log?

Comment: Looks like you are mixing releases or added repositories designed for other OS releases. Your broken fontconfig appears to be because the API changed but the soname didn't get bumped.

Comment: what 'whole log'?  what log are you talking about?

Comment: @cas  , i meant  " everything that print 'ldd /usr/bin/fc-cache' command"

Comment: Could you show the output of `head -n 50 /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`?

Comment: @Stephen Kitt  just added

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
sudo wget http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fontconfig/fontconfig-config_2.11.94-0ubuntu2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i fontconfig-config_2.11.94-0ubuntu2_all.deb
```

Comment: While the commands you suggested may answer the question, it is preferred that you explain your answer to some extent.